# Form hidden fields and security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, security

I m using hidden field in my app to add user_id to my database "Camping". I have associations "User" has many campings and "Camping" belongs_to "user".

When I run firebug or something like this, I can modify user_id value of this field. If any user puts his ID, I can modify object to other user... I want to avoid this !

My code

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

This code, is necessary because I allow only user to edit / updated / create object if they have user_id == current_user.id. 
How to fix this security problem ?

By the way, I m using devise.

### Edit with full code

My _form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(camping) do |f| %>
      <% if camping.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(camping.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this camping from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
          <% camping.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Nom du camping</label>
          <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class:"form-control", id:"name", :required => true%>
      </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Enregistrer", class:"btn btn-success" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my controller

```
    def new
          @camping = Camping.new
          @campings = Camping.all
        end


        def edit

        end
def create
      @camping = Camping.new(camping_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @camping.save
          format.html { redirect_to @camping, notice: 'Camping was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @camping }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @camping.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def update
      @camping = Camping.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
        if @camping.update(camping_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @camping, notice: 'Camping was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @camping }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @camping.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

my edit.html.erb

```
<div class="containershow">
<h1>Editing Camping</h1>

<%= render 'form', camping: @camping %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @camping %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', campings_path %>
</div>
```

my new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Camping</h1>

<%= render 'form', camping: @camping %>

<%= link_to 'Back', campings_path %>
```

### Edit solution ?

User can create and update his camping. I delete hidden_field

```
 def create
     # @camping = Camping.new(camping_params)

        @camping = Camping.new((camping_params).merge(:user_id => current_user.id))

      respond_to do |format|
        if @camping.save
          format.html { redirect_to @camping, notice: 'Camping was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @camping }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @camping.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

In Devise, the current user object is in `current_user`, available to your controllers. When saving the model, make sure to fill the user id field from that object, and not user input in the `update` action of your controller. Note that the `edit` action does not matter, that just renders the edit page, the actual update happens in `update` (if you follow the default conventions). Of course if you don't want users to even *see* other users' objects, you also need access control in other controller actions like `edit` as well, but that (implementing access control in a multi-tenant Rails application) is a different and much broader question.

More generally, be aware that anything that comes from a request can very easily be forged by a user. Always implement security server-side and do not trust user input!

**Edit** (seeing your code)

To prevent users updating others' Campings, you need to check in `update` after getting the @camping object (the second line) whether that's a camping object that your logged on user (current_user.id) is supposed to be able to edit.

The same way, if you want to prevent users from creating Campings for other users, you need to make sure in `create` that user_id will be set to the current user, something like `@camping.user_id=current_user.id`.

Similarly, if you want to prevent having a look at each other's Campings, you need to add checks to `edit`, `show` and pretty much all actions that return such objects.

There are gems like cancan and [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) that may help with access control in Rails, they are worth a look!

Comment: Thanks for this precision, so i need to do that in my controller. Please can I have an example to have current ID in controller cause I m lost... ?

Comment: Yes, in the controller. Current user id is `current_user.id` by default.

Comment: Ok but problem, I need to save my current_user.id in my forms. It's edit and new forms. So if i define this => def edit
  currentUser = current_user.id
end // and after <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => currentUser %> it's the same problem no ?

Comment: I update my question with my new controller. Is it ok for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is quite interesting but simple In the any HTML View Any one can change anything this will cause a security wise vulnerability as well.

To avoid these issues we need to authenticate it by two way You have to check the code by like It should be use by Controller not by view.

Suppose If you are creating any article of particular user

So To avoid it what you can do You can set the User ID in Session and make a Helper Method to find Current User always

So that you can find current user directly from controller and create article according to user

```
  def Create

   @article = current_user.articles.create(article_params)

  end
```

This kind of Two way checking you can put up so that It will be safe.

To avoid the spend time on these work you can use gem directly like Devise

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267321/how-to-create-current-user-method-without-using-any-gem-or-plugin Refer it as well

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my post with my code. By the way I m using devise gem.

Comment: So did you understand the thing what i m trying to say

Comment: I understand, current_user can be declare in controller not in view beauce it's not secure. But I m not sure to do that with my code... I ll try.

Comment: In your code i think you do not need to do any extra afford you have already devise gem implemented so please create a record from the current user or store that id into ur newly created record